# how to reorder my R dataframe by date and filled with NAs?

Tags: r

I want to convert dataframe df1 to df2 like the following:

```
df1 <- read.table(textConnection("
id     date    ret
1101 19900104 6.5867
1102 19900105 6.5383
1103 19900106 6.6043
1101 19900105 3.6943
1102 19900106 3.6368
1103 19900107 1.2740
1104 19900107 3.8572
1101 19900106 2.2525
1102 19900107 1.1253
1101 19900107 2.2331
"),header=T)

df2 <- read.table(textConnection("
date      1101    1102    1103     1104
19900104  6.5867  NA      NA       NA
19900105  3.6943  6.5383  NA       NA
19900106  2.2525  3.6368  6.6043   NA
19900107  2.2331  1.1253  1.2740   3.8572
"),header=T)
```

I tried to use loop but I don't think it's a good solution in case I have very large data which covers daily period from 1990 to 2012. Many thanks to anyone can help me...

Comment: It should be possible to do this with the `plyr` and/or `reshape` packages (i haven't used them myself, but seen similar questions frequently pop up so I can't help you).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is going from long to wide format. `reshape2` is a great package for working with these types of problems. To go from long to wide, you want to use `dcast()`. You give it the object to work with (`df1`), then a formula, which basically indicates what the rows are indexed by on the left of the `~` and what the columns are indexed by on the right.

```
library(reshape2)
df2 <- dcast(df1, date ~ id)
df2
#       date   1101   1102   1103   1104
# 1 19900104 6.5867     NA     NA     NA
# 2 19900105 3.6943 6.5383     NA     NA
# 3 19900106 2.2525 3.6368 6.6043     NA
# 4 19900107 2.2331 1.1253 1.2740 3.8572
```